# My Main Menu won't update when I add or remove items from it

Tags: joomla-3.4

I added a new item to my main menu but it doesn't show up on the frontend. I tried removing items as a test but that didn't work either. I cleared the expired cache and cache but the changes still aren't showing up. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to your menu item in the backend and clicking the button in the toolbar that says Rebuild Menu. Sounds like something went wonky in the menu table of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Turn system cache off in global settings.